# INSERT in to to the table based on the select max

Tags: oracle

Can anybody tell me what could be the difference in the below query which insert in to the table.

```
INSERT INTO STAGING.ASSET (ASSET_ID,ASSET,ASSET_DESC)
values ((SELECT MAX(ASSET_ID) FROM STAGING.ASSET )+ 1 ,'High Yield');
```

This one skipping one record and insert,for example I have 5 records in the `STAGING.ASSET`,after insert I could see 7 incremented value in the ASSET_ID.

```
INSERT INTO STAGING.ASSET (ASSET_ID,ASSET,ASSET_DESC)
values (SELECT MAX(ASSET_ID)+1 FROM STAGING.ASSET ,'High Yield');
```

Comment: Neither statement is valid - they don't select enough values, and the second needs parentheses around the subquery. Showing your actual queries might be helpful, since it's rather hard to tell what you're doing wrong in code we can't see; along with sample data and the actual and expected results for both.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, **No Difference** in result.

**Case 1 :**

```
INSERT INTO STAGING.ASSET (ASSET_ID,ASSET,ASSET_DESC)
values ((SELECT MAX(ASSET_ID) FROM STAGING.ASSET )+ 1 ,'High Yield');
```

Your inner query will get the `MAX` value and once inner query completed gets executed, then add +1 in it.

**Case 2 :**

```
INSERT INTO STAGING.ASSET (ASSET_ID,ASSET,ASSET_DESC)
values (SELECT MAX(ASSET_ID)+1 FROM STAGING.ASSET ,'High Yield');
```

Your inner query will get `MAX` value and add +1 in it and upon execution of inner query you will get same result as above

Comment: Thanks Ravi,yes there is no difference between them,

Comment: @avina_hello - so... what is your question then? You suggested they were getting different results, are you now saying they don't?

Comment: Alex, first I thought it would fetch max record based on the whole table,now its clear